# grant command doesn't work in mysql

Tags: mysql

I've logged in as root and typed the below command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'hive'@'master'  WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

the result is

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

the warning message is

```
Warning | 1285 | MySQL is started in --skip-name-resolve mode; you must restart it without this switch for this grant to work
```

and then I check the grants for user 'hive'

```
mysql> show grants for hive;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for hive@%                                                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'hive'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*4DF1D66463C18D44E3B001A8FB1BBFBEA13E27FC' |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and I tried

```
show grants for 'hive'@'master' 
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'hive' on host 'master'
```

why doesn't grant command work here?

---

I disabled skip-name-resolv in `/etc/my.cnf` and it works.
http://mysql-forum.ch/archive/index.php?thread-5.html
I think the warning is mainly caused by using the host name 'master' instead of an ip address.

But is it appropriate to set skip-name-resolv disabled in `/etc/my.cnf` or is there any other choice?

Comment: looks like it worked. What warning message did you get?

Comment: the warning says "MySQL is started in --skip-name-resolve mode; you must restart it without this switch for this grant to work"

Comment: I still encountered this on 8.0.21. It looks like a bug. Refer: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97399

Answer (score 4):

Nothing wrong with the grant statement there, you are using the `show grants` statement incorrectly. As MySQL documentation on [show grants](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-grants.html) says:

> To name the account, use the same format as for the GRANT statement; for example, 'jeffrey'@'localhost'. If you specify only the user name part of the account name, a host name part of '%' is used.

'hive'@'master' and 'hive'@'%' users are different. To show 'hive'@'master' user's grants, use the full user account name in the `show grants` statement.